# What's the most Pythonic way to remove a number from start of a string?

Tags: python

I have various strings

`123_dog`
`2_fish`
`56_cat`
`45_cat_fish`

There is always one number. Always a '_' after the number.

I need to remove the number and the underscore. I can use regex, but I wonder if there is some pythonic way that uses builtin methods?

(I'm an experienced coder - but new to Python.)

Comment: Splitting on the underscore is simplest, but if your keyboard is missing the square bracket keys you could also do `'123_dog'.lstrip('0123456789_')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that there is always an underscore after the number, and that there is always exactly a single number, you can do this:

```
s = '45_cat_fish'
print s.split('_', 1)[1]
# >>> cat_fish
```

The argument to `split` specifies the maximum number of splits to perform.

Answer (score 4):

Using split and join:

```
>>> a="45_cat_fish"
>>> '_'.join(a.split('_')[1:])
'cat_fish'
```

Edit: [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) can take a `maxsplit` argument (see [YS-L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25887775/3336968) answer), so `'_'.join` is unnecessary, `a.split('_',1)[1]`…

---

Using [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)

```
>>> a[a.find('_')+1:]
'cat_fish'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
s = "45_cat_fish"
print ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha() or c == '_')[1:]
```

gives `cat_fish`